# QGraphicsscene lags with 150+ items

Tags: c++, performance, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I am not too familiar with the performance of QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView.. I know that there is a 10 000 chips example which works well and that the QGraphicsScene is optimized for having a large amount of items in it. However, the game I made lags.( I need to note that this is my first game which actually could be called as such )

My mainloop processing looks like this:

> ```
> timer.setInterval(0);
> timer.start();
> connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(mainloop()));
> ```

inside this mainloop I update all my game logic. Everything seems to be ok, but once I go to fullscreen and I have about 100+ Items in the scene..it starts to lag and the completion of the mainloop takes (sometimes) more than 33ms. Besides the Player, I have only Objects of `GameCollectable`, you can see the update routine in the code below. Is this because I have my mainloop on the GUI Thread? Because every `GameCollectable` is rendered by an image? Should I try to make the mainloop in its own thread?

It would be really gentle of you, if someone could take a look at the update routine of my `GameCollectable` class and tell me why my code produces so much lag. I have a I5 2500K processor btw.

```
void GameCollectable::update(int t)
{
    //animationstuff
    if(t>lastframeupdate)
    {
        if(m_spawner!=NULL)
        {
            if(animindex>=m_spawner->animation_collectable_normal.get()->animationimgs.size()-1)
                animindex=0;
            m_graphicsitem->setImage( m_spawner->animation_collectable_normal.get()->getFrameImage(animindex));
            lastframeupdate=t;
            //animindex++;
        }
    }

    if(started==false)starttime=t;
    started=true;
    move(t);
}

bool GameCollectable::move(int t)
{
    float t_inc=(t-starttime)/animtime;
    //reached our destination?
    if(m_graphicsitem->pos().x()<destPos.x())
    {
        onDestination=true;
        emit signal_reached(this);
        return false;
    }
    //collided with player?
    else if(m_graphicsitem->collidesWithItem(Game::GameManager::instance()->getPlayer()->getGraphicsItem()))
    {
        Game::SoundManager::instance()->playCoinPickup(t);
        bumpedPlayer=true;
        emit signal_bumped(this);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        m_graphicsitem->setPos(lerp(startPos.x(),destPos.x(),t_inc),m_graphicsitem->pos().y());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try disabling various parts of your code and find which one is slow. For example, comment out the collision detection code, then the image loading code, etc. Also try running in release mode as it's normally a lot faster.

Comment: A profiler is your friend.